# autocomplete off still keep history?

Tags: html, autocomplete

Did puting autocomplete off on input text say to the browser to not remember the text or only not using it?

I have textbox with personal things and I want to be sure it cannot be retrieve on a public computer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN Page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion) regarding HTML autocompletion, browsers will not save data if autocomplete is turned off for that form or field:

> Setting autocomplete="off" here has two effects:
>
> - it stops the browser saving field data for later autocompletion on similar forms though heuristics that vary by browser.
> - it stops the browser caching form data in session history. When form data is cached in session history, the information the user has filled
>     in will be visible after the user has submitted the form and clicked
>     on the Back button to go back to the original form page.

Comment: tanks, for modzilla. but that maybe said that its not every browser.